# Use generic to reduce repeated code - Method accepting two generic parameters

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection

I have a method that has a repeated set of statement that are screaming at for refactoring but I do not know how to Generics the parameters of a method that should do the repeated task.

Here is my code:

```
private void RegisterServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddTransient<CommonApiMessageHandler>();

    var baseAddress = Configuration["ApiSetup:BaseAddress"];

    services.AddHttpClient<ILookupService, LookupService>("Api.Lookup", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    }).AddHttpMessageHandler<CommonApiMessageHandler>();

    services.AddHttpClient<IBusinessLookupService, BusinessLookupService>("Api.Lookup", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    }).AddHttpMessageHandler<CommonApiMessageHandler>();

    services.AddHttpClient<IApiUserService, ApiUserService>("Api.ApiUser", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    }).AddHttpMessageHandler<CommonApiMessageHandler>();

    services.AddHttpClient<IRequestService, RequestService>("Api.Request", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    }).AddHttpMessageHandler<CommonApiMessageHandler>();

    services.AddHttpClient<IResourceService, ResourceService>("Api.Resource", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    }).AddHttpMessageHandler<CommonApiMessageHandler>();

    services.AddHttpClient<IApproverTemplateService, ApproverTemplateService>("Api.ApproverTemplate", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    }).AddHttpMessageHandler<CommonApiMessageHandler>();

    services.AddHttpClient<IAttachmentService, AttachmentService>("Api.Attachment", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    }).AddHttpMessageHandler<CommonApiMessageHandler>();

    services.AddHttpClient<IDacBudgetService, DacBudgetServiceClient>("Api.DaCBudget", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    }).AddHttpMessageHandler<CommonApiMessageHandler>();
}
```

What I feel it should be:

```
private static void NewMethod(IServiceCollection services, string baseAddress, Generic T, Generic U)
{
    services.AddHttpClient<T, U>("Api.Lookup", client =>
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    }).AddHttpMessageHandler<CommonApiMessageHandler>();
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes. It should be `private static void NewMethod<T, U>(IServiceCollection services, string baseAddress, T serviceInterface, U serviceImpl) where U : T`. You define generic parameters in angled brackets, and can then use them like types. The `where U : T` is a constraint that means that U (your service class) must implement T (your service interface), which avoids mistakes when you accidentally try to input incompatible types.

Comment: @ckuri Might want to make that your answer, not a comment.

Comment: @ckuri I get error on using `serviceInterface` & `serviceImpl`  `services.AddHttpClient<serviceInterface, serviceImpl>(name, client => { ... }`: `serviceInterface` is a variable but used as a type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not only use generics, but also define it as an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), so you can call it the same way you make other services calls.

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddMyService<TInterface,TImplementation>(this IServiceCollection services, string serviceName, string baseAddress)
        where TInterface: class 
        where TImplementation : class, TInterface
    {
        services.AddHttpClient<TInterface, TImplementation>(serviceName, client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
        }).AddHttpMessageHandler<CommonApiMessageHandler>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
services.AddMyService<IApiUserService, ApiUserService>("Api.ApiUser", baseAddress);
services.AddMyService<IRequestService, RequestService>("Api.Request", baseAddress);

//etc....
```

Or, since we return IServiceCollection, you can chain them:

```
services
    .AddMyService<IApiUserService, ApiUserService>("Api.ApiUser", baseAddress)
    .AddMyService<IRequestService, RequestService>("Api.Request", baseAddress);
```

Comment: There needs to be a return statement in the extension method?

Comment: Edited. It's nice to return `IServiceCollection` so that the caller can chain the calls.

Comment: This is perfect.